# How to read Interleaved samples using nidaqmx API

Tags: api, python-2.7, nidaqmx

I am having trouble trying to read interleaved data using a NI-USB 6353 device. I’ve looked through the Python nidaqmx API documentation to see if there is a way to do that, but there is no mention of that. Is there a way to read interleaved data through the Python API?